Is it safe to remove "binutils" packages from Debian?
I recently updated my Debian server to "latest stable" and got a message about "limited security support":

Is it safe to remove "binutils" and the packages listed under "Affected binary packages"?
My common sense screams to leave it alone as it seems to be a crucial part of the linux toolchain?

Is it safe? probably. Is it useful? unlikely. It's going to be needed again when you need to compile something. The only "security issue" with it seems to be that you should only compile trusted source code. You can check out the link in the message for the discussion about the reasoning for categorizing the package as it is.

Oh okay, good to know. I've never compiled anything on this machine and always used apt/dpkg to install packages. If I got you right, I can safely remove the mentioned packages without rendering my system unusable, if I'm not planning to compile something?
